# Published data in topic in confluent kafka showing all null values except for the ID column

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

## Avro Schema value and Avro Schema Key : [Confluent Control Center UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8e4rD.png)

```
{
  "namespace": "com.kaggle.onlineretail",
  "name": "product",
  "type": "record",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ID",
      "type": ["null", "int"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "category",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "price",
      "type": ["null", "float"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "last_updated",
      "type": ["null",{
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"   
    }]
}
  ]
}


{
    "namespace": "com.kaggle.onlineretail",
    "name": "Product",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      {
        "name": "Id",
        "type": "int"
      }
    ]
}
```

Partition key is ID

The producer script is publishing the data extracted from mysql table into topic, but on Confluent kafka site it is showing null values, attached the image.

Note : I can see data is present mysql table and even data is present when I fetched data in producer code in python

Answer (score 0):

> data is present when I fetched data in producer code in python

Producers do not "fetch". Assuming you mean consumer, then the Control Center UI has bugs when trying to use Avro (it won't even let you produce  Avro data with a schema) . Ksql UI is better, if available, otherwise you'll have to contact Confluent support.